# Crystal Report: Unhide data if it is On first Record of the page

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010, crystal-reports-formulas

I have here a data that will suppress when on change of a field.
And I made to suppress it. But I'm having trouble on displaying the record on the first line. Even it is duplicate record I need to display it.

I have tried

```
Not OnfirstRecord And
if ({onChangefield} = previous({onChangeField})) then
true
else
false
```

But it doesn't unhide the first line of the record.

Please help.

Thank you in advance. :)

Edit:

It's not "on change field", it is a key field that if this key field is duplicate then the data will suppressed.

Comment: Apologies, I put some comment as I cannot edit my question. It's not "on change field", it is a key field that if this key field is duplicate then the data will suppressed.

Answer (score 3):

You just misplace the `Not OnfirstRecord` I do like below and it's working.

```
if Not OnfirstRecord And ({onChangefield} = previous({onChangeField})) then
true
```

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do is to print the numbers on the records then supress according to that:

1. Create a formula `@Reset` :

   ```
   Shared Numbervar count;
   count:=0;
   ```
2. Create a formula `@Count`

   ```
   Shared Numbervar count;
   count:=count+1;
   ```
3. Create a formula `@display`

   ```
   Shared Numbervar count;
   count;
   ```

Now write your formula as:

```
Shared Numbervar count;

If(count=1) And ({onChangefield} = previous({onChangeField})) then
true
else
false
```

Comment: This answers misses information when to execute the formulas/where to place them.

Comment: Yes - when/where should `@Reset` be executed?

Comment: @dd4711 put the reset in report header, count in details where records are printed and supress in supress of the section. hope this helps